# Code cannot exit from GTK application - apparently no message loops

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to figure out how to get a GTK application to exit automatically after 
a certain time.

So I have a callback function which is meant to shutdown the application:

```
static gboolean killOffApp (gpointer userData) {
    gtk_main_quit ();
    return FALSE;
}
```

Then, in the `activate` signal handler, I start the five-second timer:

```
static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    g_timeout_add_seconds (5, killOffApp, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}
```

And, for completeness, here is the `main` that attaches the signal handler and runs the GTK application:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("com.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    int status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);
    return status;
}
```

My problem is that, when the timer fires, the call to `gtk_main_quit` appears to be invalid and I'm not sure why:

```
(MyProg:776): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed
```

I've researched the problem on the web but only found stuff where either:

- it's done from a part of the code where there is an inner loop running (such as in a dialog) so it shuts down that one rather than the main loop (not the case here, I believe); or
- there's no loop running since, for example, the application was run with the one-shot `gtk_main_iteration_do` (I don't think that's the case here either).

I'm obviously doing *something* wrong, why does my application appear not to have a message loop running?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `gtk_main_quit` function appears not to be suitable when using GtkApplication. From someone who has been involved in the development of various Gnome projects, one [Emmanuele Bassi](https://wiki.gnome.org/EmmanueleBassi) commented [elsewhere](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.gtk%2B.general/26483) (slightly paraphrased and noting in particular the second paragraph):

> If you're calling `g_application_run()` then you don't need to call `gtk_main()` as well: the `run()` method will spin the main loop for you.
>
> *You also don't use `gtk_main_quit()` to stop the application's main loop: you should use `g_application_quit()` instead.*

---

With that in mind, you need to pass the application to the callback, and call the application quit function with it:

```
static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    g_timeout_add_seconds (forceShutdown, killOffApp, app); // << here
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

static gboolean killOffApp (gpointer userData) {
    g_application_quit (userData); // << and here
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you call [`g_application_quit()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GApplication.html#g-application-quit) instead of `gtk_main_quit()` in your original code?

Comment: @andlabs, that works as well, once I pass the application to the callback. Will update answer.

Comment: That should probably be more clearly documented then; you can file an issue on the official GNOME bugzilla suggesting the documentation say not to call `gtk_main_quit()` if you use GtkApplication...

Comment: Trying this in Gtk 3.22.9 .., I had to pass the gpointer userData as the 2nd parameter, not the 1st one. I didn't try to use the first parameter, but just assumed it was the widget getting the destroy signal so put in GtkWidget *widget there. I also had to use G_APPLICATION(userData).

Comment: I found this useful while trying out the go bindings for gtk3 -- gotk3.

Comment: @ColinKeenan: If you are calling `g_application_quit` from a signal handler registered with `g_signal_connect`, then you're 100% correct.  The first argument is the widget and the user data is the last argument.  If you instead register with `g_signal_connect_swapped`, then the user data will come first.